# XSLT getting information from another context

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

I am trying to reference the TITLE and AUTHOR elements of a BOOK while using a for-each loop to go through each SHELF.
Here is my XML:

```
<DOC>
  <BOOKS>
    <BOOK ID="1234">
      <TITLE>Intro to XSLT</TITLE>
      <AUTHOR>Junior Writer</AUTHOR>
    </BOOK>
    <BOOK ID="1235">
      <TITLE>Advanced XSLT</TITLE>
      <AUTHOR>Senior Writer</AUTHOR>
    </BOOK>
  </BOOKS>
  <CABINET>
    <SHELF>
      <NAME>Top</NAME>
      <BOOK ID="1234"/>
      <BOOK ID="1235"/>
    </SHELF>
    <SHELF>
      <NAME>Middle</NAME>
      <BOOK ID="1235"/>
    </SHELF>
  </CABINET>
</DOC>
```

After many variations of shooting in the dark, the current XSL I am trying but is not working:

```
<xsl:for-each select="CABINET/SHELF">
    <xsl:value-of select="NAME"> Shelf:
    <xsl:for-each select="BOOK">
      <xsl:value-of select="/BOOKS/BOOK[@ID=current()/@ID]/TITLE"/> by
      <xsl:value-of select="/BOOKS/BOOK[@ID=current()/@ID]/AUTHOR"/>
    </xsl:for-each>

</xsl:for-each>
```

I would like it to show up as:

```
Top Shelf:
Intro to XSLT by
Junior Writer
Advanced XSLT by
Senior Writer

Middle Shelf:
Advanced XSLT by
Senior Writer
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a little confused by your examples. First your XML input isn't [well-formed](https://www.w3.org/TR/xml11/#sec-well-formed); you don't have a single root element. Also, in your XSLT snippet you select the `DOCUMENT` element, but that element doesn't exist in your input. (Not to mention you're missing the `=` on all of the `select` attributes.)

Otherwise your approach of using `current()` to compare `ID` attributes is correct and will work.

Another option is to use [a key](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#key).

Here are examples of both ways. If you still have problems applying these to your actual XML, update the XML in your question and I can update my answer.

**XML Input** (updated to be well-formed)

```
<DOC>
    <BOOKS>
        <BOOK ID="1234">
            <TITLE>Intro to XSLT</TITLE>
            <AUTHOR>Junior Writer</AUTHOR>
        </BOOK>
        <BOOK ID="1235">
            <TITLE>Advanced XSLT</TITLE>
            <AUTHOR>Senior Writer</AUTHOR>
        </BOOK>
    </BOOKS>
    <CABINET>
        <SHELF>
            <NAME>Top</NAME>
            <BOOK ID="1234"/>
            <BOOK ID="1235"/>
        </SHELF>
        <SHELF>
            <NAME>Middle</NAME>
            <BOOK ID="1235"/>
        </SHELF>
    </CABINET>
</DOC>
```

**Option #1** ([fiddle](http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NzcBsP))

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:for-each select="CABINET/SHELF">
      <xsl:if test="position() > 1"><xsl:text>&#xA;&#xA;</xsl:text></xsl:if>      
      <xsl:value-of select="NAME"/>
      <xsl:text> Shelf:&#xA;</xsl:text> 
      <xsl:for-each select="BOOK">
        <xsl:if test="position() > 1"><xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text></xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="/DOC/BOOKS/BOOK[@ID = current()/@ID]/TITLE"/>
        <xsl:text> by&#xA;</xsl:text> 
        <xsl:value-of
          select="/DOC/BOOKS/BOOK[@ID = current()/@ID]/AUTHOR"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Option #2** ([fiddle](http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NzcBsP/1))

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="books" match="BOOK" use="@ID"/>

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:for-each select="CABINET/SHELF">
      <xsl:if test="position() > 1"><xsl:text>&#xA;&#xA;</xsl:text></xsl:if>      
      <xsl:value-of select="NAME"/>
      <xsl:text> Shelf:&#xA;</xsl:text> 
      <xsl:for-each select="BOOK">
        <xsl:if test="position() > 1"><xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text></xsl:if>
        <xsl:value-of select="key('books',@ID)/TITLE"/>
        <xsl:text> by&#xA;</xsl:text> 
        <xsl:value-of select="key('books',@ID)/AUTHOR"/>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Both of these options produce the following output:

```
Top Shelf:
Intro to XSLT by
Junior Writer
Advanced XSLT by
Senior Writer

Middle Shelf:
Advanced XSLT by
Senior Writer
```

You could also use a push-style instead of a pull-style which would make your stylesheet easier to extend if/when it gets more complicated...

**Option #2 push-style** ([fiddle](http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/3NzcBsP/3))

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:key name="books" match="BOOK" use="@ID"/>

  <xsl:template match="/DOC">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="CABINET/SHELF"/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="SHELF[position() > 1]">
    <xsl:text>&#xA;&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="NAME">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <xsl:text> Shelf:</xsl:text>     
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="BOOK">
    <xsl:text>&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('books',@ID)/TITLE"/>
    <xsl:text> by&#xA;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="key('books',@ID)/AUTHOR"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Thank you , Daniel.   As this is my first post here, I was more focused on getting the code to end up in their boxes than I was at getting my syntax correct.  I deserved every one of your criticisms.  I am sure all of your solutions work.   Unfortunately, I am only able to enter code within a small segment of the overall work. When I tried using either "key" solution it errors due to me not being able to declare the key at the top-level of the stylesheet.